# Mysql8 Unable to order the result of WITH RECURSIVE query

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0, cte, recursive

I am using the `WITH RECURSIVE` query to generate a hierarchy of users. The data and the query used is shared in https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oTbCcMQb5a4B6V96DAYJHG/0 . The query is returning the results correctly, but the order of the data is different from what i need.

I have tweaked the query a few times, but unable to achieve the required result.
**Actual Result of the query**

```
+-----+--------+------------+------------+
| id  | title  | parent_id  | sort_order |
+-----+--------+------------+------------+
|  1  | null   | null       |          0 |
|  2  | A      | 1          |          1 |
|  3  | B      | 1          |          2 |
|  4  | AA     | 2          |          1 |
|  5  | AB     | 2          |          2 |
| 13  | BA     | 3          |          1 |
| 17  | BC     | 3          |          2 |
|  6  | AAA    | 4          |          1 |
|  7  | AAB    | 4          |          2 |
|  8  | AAC    | 4          |          3 |
|  9  | ABA    | 5          |          1 |
| 10  | ABB    | 5          |          2 |
| 11  | ABC    | 5          |          3 |
| 12  | ABD    | 5          |          4 |
| 16  | BAA    | 13         |          1 |
+-----+--------+------------+------------+
```

**Result I am trying to achieve**

```
+-----+--------+------------+------------+
| id  | title  | parent_id  | sort_order |
+-----+--------+------------+------------+
|  1  | null   | null       |          0 |
|  2  | A      | 1          |          1 |
|  4  | AA     | 2          |          1 |
|  6  | AAA    | 4          |          1 |
|  7  | AAB    | 4          |          2 |
|  8  | AAC    | 4          |          3 |
|  5  | AB     | 2          |          2 |
|  9  | ABA    | 5          |          1 |
| 10  | ABB    | 5          |          2 |
| 11  | ABC    | 5          |          3 |
| 12  | ABD    | 5          |          4 |
|  3  | B      | 1          |          2 |
| 13  | BA     | 3          |          1 |
| 16  | BAA    | 13         |          1 |
| 17  | BC     | 3          |          2 |
+-----+--------+------------+------------+
```

In my query the `WITH RECURSIVE` will take all nodes of level 1, then it will take all level2 and continues..

But the result I am trying to achieve is take first node of first level, complete the hierarchy, the take second element of the first level and recurse through rest.

Is is possible to get this result using `WITH RECURSIVE`

> The data in the title is sample data, so that it is easy to understand the hierarchy.

Comment: It works fine [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oTbCcMQb5a4B6V96DAYJHG/1) if I added  `order by title asc`

Comment: @ErgestBasha the name is just a dummy values. The real values are different.

Comment: *but the order of the data is different from what i need* If you need in definite rows ordering then you must use according ORDER BY in outer query. Recursive CTE returns  output rows ordered by the order in which they were selected and placed into the output buffer.

Comment: *The real values are different* This means that your simplified model provided as your data is not adequate. Add another sample data. See [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055), #5 and #3.

Comment: @Akina What I meant was a ordering by title will not produce the expected result. I have added more info on the question, may be that will avoid the confusions.

Comment: @NandakumarV Common solution - synthetic pseudo-title column (which is fully qualified path in practice) built with rows enumeration with leading zeros. Alternatively you may use rows' numeric PK values. This pseudo-title column can be used for final sorting.

Comment: @NandakumarV - Your "Result I am trying to achieve" looks like `ORDER BY title`.  I see no relevance _to the output_ of the other columns.